# Move plugin modification outside of plugin files

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a plugin called [wp show posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-show-posts/) to list posts from specific categories on pages. I'm also using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/), with which I added meta values to all of the posts (active, new, and/or closed). I modified the wp show posts plugin to display the meta data values on each post title when they're in list view.

```
                    // The title
                if ( $settings[ 'include_title' ] || ( $settings[ 'include_author' ] && 'below-title' == $settings[ 'author_location' ] ) || ( $settings[ 'include_date' ] && 'below-title' == $settings[ 'date_location' ] ) || ( $settings[ 'include_terms' ] && 'below-title' == $settings[ 'terms_location' ] ) ) : ?>

          <?php if( get_field('new') ): ?>
             <h2 class="new"><?php the_field('new'); ?></h2>
          <?php endif; ?>    
          <?php if( get_field('active') ): ?>
             <h2 class="active"><?php the_field('active'); ?></h2>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php if( get_field('closed') ): ?>
             <h2 class="closed"><?php the_field('closed'); ?></h2>
          <?php endif; ?>

        <header class="wp-show-posts-entry-header">
```

You can see the code I added there in between the title function and header function.

Now that I've modified the plugin, I won't be able to update it.

Where can I place this code so it won't be inside the plugin files?

Comment: Unless the plugin includes a hook for what you want to do, there is no real way to modify its output without modifying the plugin itself. You'll likely either need to re-add your code whenever you update the plugin, or I suppose you could generate your html via PHP and then insert it where you want it to go via Javascript?

Comment: Editing plugin's code directly isn't recommended for that very same reason: you won't be able to update it without losing your custom modifications, which could make your site insecure in the future. Instead, you should try using the filter/action hooks provided by the plugin to modify its behavior whenever possible. Please check my answer below and, if it helped, consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Got it, thank you all for your input. I'll stay away from editing the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP Show Posts has an action hook called `wpsp_before_title` that you can use to insert content before the heading:

```
/**
 * Adds ACF data before the heading.
 *
 * @param array $settings
 */
function wpsp_show_acf_data( $settings ){
    <?php if( get_field('new') ): ?>
        <h2 class="new"><?php the_field('new'); ?></h2>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if( get_field('active') ): ?>
        <h2 class="active"><?php the_field('active'); ?></h2>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if( get_field('closed') ): ?>
        <h2 class="closed"><?php the_field('closed'); ?></h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
}
add_action( 'wpsp_before_title', 'wpsp_show_acf_data' );
```

Add this to your theme's `functions.php` file (or to a standalone plugin) and it should work.

Remember to undo the modifications you made to the plugin since you won't need them anymore.